# javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal whitespace in address in string

Tags: java

i'm using a .properties file containing my emailserver name and sender and receiver adresses :

```
printServer=xxx.Xxx.xxx
sender=xxxx-xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xxx
receiver=xxxx-xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xxx
```

When i try to retrieve the sender value i'm getting this error :

```
 javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal whitespace in address in string ``!!key =sender!!''
 fr.srd.remap.runtime.PclReportGenerator.sendReporttest(PclReportGenerator.java:120)
... 40 more
```

here the method i used :

```
 public static String getString(String key, String bundleName) {
try {
  ResourceBundle        resourceBundle;

  resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName);

  System.out.println(resourceBundle.getString(key));
  return resourceBundle.getString(key);
} catch (MissingResourceException e) {
  return "!!key =" + key + "!!";
}
}
```

Here the principle error :

`java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name server, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:724)`

i named the properties file :server.properties so what's wrong with the name , i even test it with this name server_en.properties but the problem persists.

Comment: Why don't you take a step back and figure why it threw `MissingResourceException`? All consequences like the `AddressException` are completely irrelevant to the core problem and only adds noise to the question. Try to think logically.

Comment: @BalusC i added the principle error

Answer (score 0):

Dump the bundlename (and `e.getMessage()`). Like "xxx.yyy.zzz" for a `/xxx/yyy/zzz.properties`. Inspect the jar with 7zip or WinZip, and check that the path is case-sensitive.